# php settype() int always returns 1

Tags: php, types, integer, set

I am getting a variable from `$_GET['category']`. This is always supposed to be a integer. So when I set the variable I use:

```
$category=settype($_GET['category'], "int");
// Also tried
$category=settype($_GET['category'], "integer");
```

However, this always returns 1. They are numbers in the query string for example:

http://domain.com/example.php?category=57

When I `echo $category` it always returns 1. No mater what `?category=` has behind it for a number.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`settype`](http://php.net/settype) *modifies* the type of the variable. You're using it as if it would *return* a new variable.

However, `settype` returns true if the type change was successful, and false otherwise. You're seeing the result `1` since that's the string representation of true.

You should either use [casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting), or [intval](http://php.net/intval):

```
$category = (int) $_GET['category']; // or ...
$category = intval($_GET['category']);
```

Comment: Gotta hate SO's random answer ordering sometimes :(

Answer (score 1):

> `settype` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

It does not return the value, it just returns whether setting the type was successful or not. Your `$_GET['category']` variable is now an `int`. If you want to do a cast which returns the value but leaves the variable untouched, the syntax is:

```
$category = (int)$_GET['category'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for [`settype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php). FYI, its return value is `bool`.

Instead, try casting, eg

```
$category = (int) $_GET['category'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) properly.

The first argument is [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). So no need to set return value in another variable.

You just do like,

```
$category = $_GET['category'];
settype($category, "integer");
```

Thanks.