# PHP settype function always returns true

Tags: php

The return type of `settype()` function in PHP is `BOOLEAN` but i always find the return type as `TRUE` i.e `1` no matter how weird and incomprehensible a conversion i try to perform.

How to have an unsuccessful typecasting thereby showing `0` as the return of the conversion.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923477/php-setttype-int-always-returns-1

Comment: @DaveChen : I went through that post. The question arose as the poster most probably was not aware that the return type of settype is BOOLEAN.

Comment: Realized my mistake and deleted it. Saw the comments after. Sorry for jumping to conclusions.

Comment: My issue here is regarding instances when we will get an FALSE return type of a type-casting operation so as to be careful n aware in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the PHP source code of [type.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/type.c#L91) you can see that there are only 2 cases where `settype` will return false: when you try to convert to a resource or when you try to convert to an unknown type:

```
$x = "";
var_dump(settype($x, "resource"));
// will return bool(false) and issue a warning
var_dump(settype($x, "bla"));
// will return bool(false) and issue a warning
```

Therefore `settype` is not useful when you want to verify the result of a type conversion.

Comment: well done, I didn't find `resource` in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) though, but I can see it clearly in the source.

Comment: Just did the same thing to fix my error. There is a third option for false though: an empty type will also issue a warning and bool false http://codepad.org/e3zFh9Ld

Comment: True. After all that would qualify as an "unknown type" as well, just the warning is different.

Comment: @HugoDelsing I would qualify that as an unknown type (= any type that doesn't match the listed ones)

Comment: You'll also get an error if you try out `$var = new stdClass(); settype($var, 'string');`.

Comment: @ALL :Thanks..!! got my cases..!!

Comment: @h2ooooooo Indeed, but it's a fatal error and not a return value `false`